# Building Crystal Report from scratch using SQL/commands

Tags: sql, sql-server, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I am trying to create a rolling unit sales history report(which will, in turn, be used to forecast sales) from scratch using Commands. I determined I can't build this through conventional means because there will simply be too many formulas.

I've succeeded in pulling unit sales and creating a header for the field that specifies the data is for Sept 2011 (36 mos ago). Here is my SQL for that:

```
SELECT "SalesTable"."UnitSalesQty" - "SalesTable"."UnitReturnQty" AS "NetQty36"
        , DATEADD(m, -36, GETDATE() - day(GETDATE() - 1)) AS "M36"
        , "ItemTable"."ItemNum" 
    FROM "ERP_app"."dbo"."SalesTable" "SalesTable" 
        INNER JOIN "ERP_app"."dbo"."ItemTable" "ItemTable" 
            ON "ItemTable"."ItemKey"="SalesTable"."ItemKey" 
    WHERE "SalesTable"."SalesDate" 
            BETWEEN DATEADD(m, -36, GETDATE() - day(GETDATE() - 1)) 
                AND DATEADD(m, -35, GETDATE() - day(GETDATE() - 1)) - 1 
        AND "ItemNum" = '1000'
```

I'm only selecting one item now for simplicity's sake.

My issue is, when I want to add Oct 2011, I don't know whether to add to this command or to create a new one. I've tried both. When I add to this command, I get error messages because the syntax with the date parameters is wrong. When I try create a new command with the "36's" changed to "35's" and add the data to the report, my Sept 2011 totals (which were right using the above command) end up too high.

I'm an accounting/finance guy by trade so please pardon any ignorance on my part.

EDIT:

Per request, [here](http://sosteppenwolf.weebly.com/uploads/1/3/5/2/13528680/6451636_orig.png) (I don't have the rep to post images) is a screenshot with the above code. The details represent each sales order. The sum is correct - 315 units for this month. I want add more columns to the right (Oct-11, Nov-11,...Jul-14, Aug-13) with their respective unit sales totals.

EDIT 2:

I was able to work the answer out from someone else's question. Here's the gist of it:

```
SELECT  DATEADD(m, -36, GETDATE()-day(GETDATE()-1)) AS  "MM36"
 , DATEADD(m, -35, GETDATE()-day(GETDATE()-1)) AS  "MM35"
```

...

```
 , DATEADD(m, -02, GETDATE()-day(GETDATE()-1)) AS  "MM02"
 , DATEADD(m, -01, GETDATE()-day(GETDATE()-1)) AS  "MM01"
 , "timItem"."ItemID"
 , SUM (CASE WHEN "SalesTable"."SalesDate" BETWEEN DATEADD(m, -36, GETDATE()-day(GETDATE()-1)) AND DATEADD(m, -35, GETDATE()-day(GETDATE()-1))-1 THEN "SalesTable"."UnitSalesQty" - "SalesTable"."UnitReturnQty"  ELSE NULL END) AS "NetQty36"
 , SUM (CASE WHEN "SalesTable"."SalesDate" BETWEEN DATEADD(m, -35, GETDATE()-day(GETDATE()-1)) AND DATEADD(m, -34, GETDATE()-day(GETDATE()-1))-1 THEN "SalesTable"."UnitSalesQty" - "SalesTable"."UnitReturnQty" ELSE NULL END) AS "NetQty35"
```

...

```
 , SUM (CASE WHEN "SalesTable"."SalesDate" BETWEEN DATEADD(m, -02, GETDATE()-day(GETDATE()-1)) AND DATEADD(m, -01, GETDATE()-day(GETDATE()-1))-1 THEN "SalesTable"."UnitSalesQty" - "SalesTable"."UnitReturnQty" ELSE NULL END) AS "NetQty02"
 , SUM (CASE WHEN "SalesTable"."SalesDate" BETWEEN DATEADD(m, -01, GETDATE()-day(GETDATE()-1)) AND DATEADD(m, -00, GETDATE()-day(GETDATE()-1))-1 THEN "SalesTable"."UnitSalesQty" - "SalesTable"."UnitReturnQty" ELSE NULL END) AS "NetQty01"

FROM "ERP_app"."dbo"."SalesTable" "SalesTable"
 INNER JOIN "ERP_app"."dbo"."ItemTable" "ItemTable" 
     ON "ItemTable"."ItemKey"="SalesTable"."ItemKey"

WHERE "ItemNum" = '1000'

GROUP BY "ItemNum"
```

Comment: Please, provide us with some sample data and the desired result so that one of the community member may better help you with your issue. Working with the query itself won't help us help you. Besides, show us what you have done so far so that one might even correct your statement so that it passes against SQL Server.

Comment: I elaborated on my question as you asked. Please see above edit.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this? Then you don't have to try to find the last day of the month...

```
   SELECT "SalesTable"."UnitSalesQty" - "SalesTable"."UnitReturnQty" AS "NetQty36"
            , DATEADD(m, -36, GETDATE() - day(GETDATE() - 1)) AS "M36"
            , "ItemTable"."ItemNum" 
        FROM "ERP_app"."dbo"."SalesTable" "SalesTable" 
            INNER JOIN "ERP_app"."dbo"."ItemTable" "ItemTable" 
                ON "ItemTable"."ItemKey"="SalesTable"."ItemKey" 
        WHERE MONTH("SalesTable"."SalesDate")
                BETWEEN MONTH(DATEADD(m, -36, GETDATE())) 
                    AND MONTH(DATEADD(m, -35, GETDATE()))
          AND YEAR("SalesTable"."SalesDate") = YEAR(DATEADD(yy,-2,GETDATE()))
            AND "ItemNum" = '1000'
```

Comment: I appreciate the input, but my syntax for the date works okay. That is, until I try to add the following month's data. I edited my question to make my issue a little more clear.